# Type '(String, AnyObject)' has no subscript members

Tags: swift

I've been through similar questions but still do not understand why my code is throwing an error.

```
let posts = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as?[String: AnyObject]
                print(posts)

                for post in posts! {
                    var postObject:Post?
                    if let id = post["ID"] as? Int , let name = post["Country_Name"]as? String{ //Type '(String, AnyObject)' has no subscript members
                        postObject = Post(ID: id, Name: name)
                        self.CountryId.append(id)
                    }
                    self.CountrySelected.append(postObject!)
```

> json data :

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "ID": 1,
    "Country_Name": "sample string 2"
  },
  {
    "$ref": "1"
  }
]
```

when i use [[[String: AnyObject]]

error : `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

why?

Comment: The answer is obvious if you will examine what you got when you said `print(posts)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is this very curious phrase

```
for post in posts
```

The problem is that `posts` is a dictionary (not an array). So you are asking to cycle *through a dictionary*. That is a very strange thing to do. And the result when you do it is a little strange: each time through the cycle, you get a *tuple* representing one key-value pair.

Comment: when i use [[String,Anyobject]] error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Answer (score 2):

```
let posts = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as?[String: AnyObject]
```

is `let posts: [String: AnyObject] = …`. This makes `posts` a dictionary.

```
for post in posts! {
```

is iterating a dictionary, so it's type is `for post: (String, AnyObject) in …`

If you want an array of dictionaries, then you need `[[String: AnyObject]]`.

```
let posts = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as?[[String: AnyObject]]
```

With that change, then

```
for post in posts! {
```

has the type `for post: [String: AnyObject] in …`.

Comment: `If you want an array of dictionaries, then you need` Well, not so fast. It all depends on whether the JSON _is_ in fact an array of dictionaries. You can't turn a silk purse into a sow's ear just by calling it a sow's ear.

Comment: @matt Yes, I don't know what the JSON looks like. That is why I said *if you want*. I'm just attempting to match the rest of his logic with the smallest change.

Comment: when i use [[String,Anyobject]] error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: @J.Arji The answer is in the error message "JSON text did not start with array or object". I would suggest you print out `data` and see what you have. Use `NSString(data:data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)` to get the data as a string.